# Replacing a surface instead of blitting to it

Tags: python, pygame

I'm having some performance issues in pygame, so I'm trying to optimize the rendering.

Currently, I'm blitting the background image to the display buffer:

```
self.display.blit(self.bg, (0, 0))
```

Instead, I'm looking for a way to replace the buffer with a copy of the background surface, and draw over that. This way, I don't have to blit a large image every frame, saving me some time.

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: maybe build your entire frame onto the self.bg surface and only blit it to the display once you're done constructing the whole image? i'm not sure there's a way to default the display to an image

Comment: @vencaslac that's what I'm doing right now, but that has no effective performance increase. Also, it doesn't clear the image, which I'm still trying to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter *that* much how often you blit something to the screen surface, since the display does only get updated once you call `pygame.display.update` or `pygame.display.flip`.

If you're sure that blitting the whole background image to the screen surface *is* a bottle neck in your game, you can try the following things:

a) Instead of blitting the whole background every frame, use the [`clear()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.clear) function to "erase" your sprites from the screen.

b) Instead of calling `pygame.display.flip` or `pygame.display.update` without an argument, call `pygame.display.update` with the list of the areas on the screen that have been changed, which is returned by the [`draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.RenderUpdates.draw) function (maybe in combination with `clear()`).

c) Create your display surface with the `FULLSCREEN`, `DOUBLEBUF` and `HWSURFACE` flags.

But as I already said: make sure you know where your bottle neck is. Some common performance pitfalls are: loading images multiple times from disk, font rendering, using different pixel formats (e.g. not calling `convert`/`convert_alpha` on surfaces created from images) and generally the lack of caching.

*(also note that python/pygame is generally not the first choice when creating graphically demanding games)*

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code it will be hard to really see where the bottleneck is. Sloth is correct on his points as a way to optimize. in my experience all images should be pre-processed outside of the main game loop by drawing them onto their own surfaces. Blitting surfaces to surfaces is much faster than blitting images to surfaces.

```
img_surface = pygame.Surface((img_rect.width, img_rect.height), pygame.SRCALPHA)
img_surface.fill((0, 0, 0, 0))
img_surface.blit(get_image("my_image.png"), img_rect)
```

This happens outside the game loop. In the game loop you blit the image surface to your surface. If you really want to evaluate you code, use cProfile. This will help you nail down exactly where the bottleneck is. Do as much pre-processing outside the main game loop as possible.

[Python getting meaningful results from cProfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21274898/python-getting-meaningful-results-from-cprofile)

This link really helped me understand cProfile. Sloth is also correct in that pygame is limited, so you are going to need to optimize everything as much as you can. That is where cProfile comes in.

...Also, make sure you are only drawing things that are visible to the user. That can really help improve performance.